# PHP nullable type declaration

Tags: php, function, methods, parameters, nullable

Is there any difference between this function in PHP 7.4?

```
public function foo(string $argumentThatCanBeNull = null) {}

public function bar(?string $argumentThatCanBeNull = null) {}
```

Comment: In PHP 7.4 you don't  need `= null`. `?string $argumentThatCanBeNull` is fine.

Comment: You need it if you want to pass no parameters to these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference as string is nullable by default.

Btw, this was introduced in PHP 7.1: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php